# Is $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}U_i$ is empty or non -empty?

Tags: general-topology

let $U_1\supset U_2\supset\cdots$  be decreasing sequence of open set in euclidean space $\mathbb R^3$.

What can we say about the set $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}U_i$?

A. it is infinite

B. It is open

C. It is non- empty

D. None of the above.

My attepmts ; i was googling it  i got some hints that it is  given that [image]

from this i can conclude that its intersection is  nonempty,,,, so  $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}U_i$ is non empty ..and my answer is option C that is non- empty.

Is my answer is correct or not, PLiz verified my mistake and  tell me the solution i would be more thankful..

Comment: But the $U_i$ are not necessarily compact, are they? They are open. That is a different concept.

Comment: You found a good hint… but there is no assumption made in your task that the sets are nonempty. So $U_i$ could be empty from an $i$ on then the result set is empty as well.

Comment: @Gono It might be that $\supset$ stands for *proper* supset.

Comment: @drhab unfortunately that's not always that clear if not mentioned exactly :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is D. If $U_n=(n,+\infty)$, then the intersection is empty. And if $U_n=\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$ then the intersection is $\{0\}$.

Comment: thank a  lots  @ Jose carlos santos .. i have vote up u now

Comment: @lomberlego Thank you but, again, what you perhaps could do would be to mark one of the answers as the accepted answer, by clicking the ✓ symbol below the downvote arrow.

Comment: ok,,,i was  not noticed about its,,, i was thinking      near  oldest ,,the votes option is there,,, i was clicking on the vote option,,,last time also i  was clicking on the vote option,,,,,,now i  notice  that  it is below  the downvote option....@ jose carlos santos......i will   click now  and previous one also i will clicks  now,,,,,,,,

Comment: @lomberlego Thank you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos isn't empty set both open and close? But $\{0\}$ is closed set implying set cannot be open. So the best choice rather would be none of the above

Comment: @KilluaZoldyck Indeed. And I wrote that the answer is D. And option D is “None of the above”.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is "none of the above". Indeed :

- Consider the open ball $U_n$ with center (0,0,0) and radius $1/n$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}^\star$). We have :$$\bigcap_{n\ge1}U_n=\{(0,0,0)\}$$which proves that the intersection has no reason to be open and no reason to be infinite.
- Consider $V_n=U_n\cap H$, where $H=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3;\,x>0\}$. It is readily seen that :$$\bigcap_{n\ge1}V_n=\emptyset $$

Comment: im not getting ur second sentence Vn = Un ∩ H  =  Ø @ Adren

Comment: @lomber lego : I am not saying that $U_n\cap H=\emptyset$, but that the intersection of all those sets is empty. Indeed, if you pick $(x,y,z)$ in the intersection, you must have $x^2+y^2+z^2<1/n^2$ for *all* $n\ge1$, hence $x=y=z=0$ and in the same time $x>0$, which is not possible.

Comment: ok..thanks @Adren

Answer (score 0):

A and C are trivial false since $\varnothing$ can be in the sequence. B is false by considering the counterexample $U_i:=(B_{1/i}(\vec x))_{i \in\mathbb N}$ for $\vec x\in\mathbb R^3$. Hence the answer should be D.

Edit: if one need it to be strictly increasing, one may consider 
$$U_i:=(B_{1/i}(\vec 0)\cap (0,1)^3)_{i \in\mathbb N}$$

Comment: I think the sequence is supposed to be strictly decreasing.

Comment: im not getting ur symbol Ui=B1/i  @ BAI

Comment: @lomberlego I mean the open ball centered at $\vec x$ with radius $1/i$.

Comment: @tomasz edited.